# Display custom models with Interactive Markers

Tags: ros, rviz, interactive-markers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am writing an RVIZ panel for performing user guided model registration in a point cloud scene.

For the purposes of performing user guided ICP, I would like to display a custom model in the centre of an interactive marker.

However, I'm unable to find documentation on how to do so. I've looked through interactive markers, but nothing suggests they support this functionality. What's the best way to achieve a custom model in an interactive marker?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/74863/display-custom-models-with-interactive-markers/) by [ehuang](https://answers.ros.org/users/6034/ehuang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-08-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just add a control with interaction type none and put a mesh or triangle list or points marker or whatever you want to have there in it.

---

Originally posted by [dgossow](https://answers.ros.org/users/1564/dgossow/) with karma: 1444 on 2013-09-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0